# error during build: RollupError: "default" is not exported by "ckeditor5/build/ckeditor.js"

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, vite, ckeditor5

I'm presenting this issue at compile my Vuejs - Laravel (Inertia - Jetstream) project where I use **ckeditor5 online custom build**, but the thing is when I execute npm run dev it works correctly but when I want to compile I get the error:

```
"default" is not exported by "ckeditor5/build/ckeditor.js", imported by "resources/js/OwnComponents/Ckeditor.vue".
file: C:/apache/htdocs/Portfolio-CMS/resources/js/OwnComponents/Ckeditor.vue:5:7
3: import { ref, watch } from 'vue';
4: // import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
5: import ClassicEditor from 'ckeditor5-custom-build';
          ^
6: import UploadAdapter from './uploadadapter.js'
error during build:
RollupError: "default" is not exported by "ckeditor5/build/ckeditor.js", imported by "resources/js/OwnComponents/Ckeditor.vue".
    at error (file:///C:/apache/htdocs/Portfolio-CMS/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:2287:30)
    at Module.error (file:///C:/apache/htdocs/Portfolio-CMS/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13745:16)
    at Module.traceVariable (file:///C:/apache/htdocs/Portfolio-CMS/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:14175:29)
    at ModuleScope.findVariable (file:///C:/apache/htdocs/Portfolio-CMS/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:12615:39)
    at FunctionScope.findVariable (file:///C:/apache/htdocs/Portfolio-CMS/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:7124:38)
    at ChildScope.findVariable (file:///C:/apache/htdocs/Portfolio-CMS/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:7124:38)
    at Identifier.bind (file:///C:/apache/htdocs/Portfolio-CMS/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:8319:40)
    at CallExpression.bind (file:///C:/apache/htdocs/Portfolio-CMS/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:5888:28)
    at CallExpression.bind (file:///C:/apache/htdocs/Portfolio-CMS/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:9890:15)
    at VariableDeclarator.bind (file:///C:/apache/htdocs/Portfolio-CMS/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:5892:23)
```

[After execute npm run build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9mSO.png)

My dependencies:

```
"vite": "^4.0.0",
"vue": "^3.2.31"

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^39.0.2",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue": "^5.1.0",
"ckeditor5-custom-build": "file:ckeditor5"
```

vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],

    optimizeDeps: {
        include: ['ckeditor5-custom-build']
    },
    build: {
        commonjsOptions: {
            exclude: ['ckeditor5-custom-build']
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
        alias: {
            '@': '/resources/js'
        }
    }
});
```

app.js:

```
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue';
...

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue)
            .use(CKEditor)
            .use(PrimeVue)
            .component('MultiSelect',MultiSelect)
            .component('Chips',Chips)
            .mount(el);
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#4B5563',
    },
});
```

ckeditor.vue:

```
import ClassicEditor from 'ckeditor5-custom-build';
...

const editor = ref(ClassicEditor);
const editorConfig = ref({
    // The configuration of the editor.
    extraPlugins: [uploader],
});
const text = ref(props.modelValue);

<ckeditor :editor="editor" v-model="text" :config="editorConfig"></ckeditor>
```

At local server / dev server all works correctly but when I want to compile I get the error.

I have the entire code here if you want to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/axlkun/AxelPortfolio-CMS in the **test** branch

I want to compile the project (npm run build), in dev server works fine but I get the error while compiling